# Is Include() method case insensitive?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I hav a code where Include method contains lowerd name of navigation property (Include("descriptions")  whereas its name is Descriptions). It executes well. So I conclude method is case insensitive.  Is it always by default or should some parameters be tuned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand the question correctly, but maybe you can use lambda in this case?

```
context.Something.Include(m => m.Descriptions)
```

SQL Server by default is case-insensitive and Entity Framework is using (T-)SQL, so that's probably the reason why it doesn't matter.

Comment: The question is why Include("descriptions") works for the entity but proprty's name is Descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it *does* work, I would recommend being explicit and exact. You're working in C# which is case sensitive so anyone that has to pickup your project will likely be confused by something that works insensitive to case (as it appears you are).

To avoid the confusion altogether, @Tx3's suggestion is really the most clear and it'll eliminate the need for EF to have to reflect to find the navigation property.

Comment: I think you are right. And it's me who is confused. It's not my code. So I'm curious about possible pitfalls.

Comment: Why risk potential pitfalls when there is an option available which would eliminate them?

Comment: Sure, no reason. I've changed the code. But want to understand the guts of the technology.

Comment: The best way to get at the "guts" are to use a decompiler like ILSpy or Reflector...